# pause all html5 videos when play specific video jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 10 html5 videos in the same page,

**PROBLEM**

when I click in different videos, they play at the same time...

```
  <div><video class="SetVideo"></video><button class="videoP"></button></div>
      <div><video class="SetVideo"></video><button class="videoP"></button></div>
  <div><video class="SetVideo"></video><button class="videoP"></button></div>
  <div><video class="SetVideo"></video><button class="videoP"></button></div>
  <div><video class="SetVideo"></video><button class="videoP"></button></div>
  <div><video class="SetVideo"></video><button class="videoP"></button></div>
  <div><video class="SetVideo"></video><button class="videoP"></button></div>
```

**How do I pause all the videos once I click play in an specific video?**

I have this so far, but nothing

```
  $(".videoP").on("click",function(){ 


   $(document).find("video").pause();
$(this).closest("div").find(".SetVideo").play();
 });
```

But it doesn work

Comment: You need  to supply more details, how you have embedded the video?

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
$(".videoP").on("click",function(){
    $('.SetVideo').trigger('pause');                       // Matches all videos with class videoP
    $(this).parent().find('.SetVideo').trigger('play');   // Should match the video corresponding to the clicked button
});
```

Comment: I was about to suggest the same

Comment: it  just pause all the videos, included the on I want to play, isnt a `pause()` callback?

Comment: Though it's a bit unclear whether you want them to pause and play when the user clicks on the video, or when they click on a button (see my edit).

Comment: when the button is clicked.

Comment: @joe I haven't tried this in action, so please let me know if it doesn't work. But this should first call `.pause()` on all the videos, and then `.play()` on the current video.

Comment: no it doesnt work. I think it need a callback after pause()

Comment: Sorry, silly mistake on my part! I should try my code before posting :)
Does it work for you now?